# My spare bathroom has several areas where paint is peeling off How can I fix this to repaint the area?

Tags: bathroom, drywall, paint, spackling-paste

I’ve sanded the spots to remove any flaking paint and smooth the surface. I then spackled one of the spots and noticed there was air bubbles like under the paint and spackle. I tried to just paint over a different spot without using spackle first. It seems to be okay. I just want to know what caused this to happen only in certain areas on the wall and how to fix it the correct way.

Thank you !
[image] This is just one of the spots

Comment: Moisture in the wall or bad paint preparation.  Prep is about 90% of a good long lasting paint job.  It consists of of good cleaning, removing of all loose paint, sanding if needed, and more cleaning.  Then you can paint.  Moisture in the wall requires fixing of the leak, usually pipes or roof, sometimes siding/windows.